# How to start ignite on single node

Tags: java, ignite

> I have a requirement where I need to use Apache Ignite using **only one node**. Could you please help how to do that?

We want it to run as a standlone.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a Server node will form a cluster of single node when it can *self-discover*, that is, it can find its IP address in what Discovery returns. If it can't, it will [wait for any nodes from Discovery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#section-static-ip-based-discovery) to show up.

So you should just launch your Server node with the following discovery config:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
    <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <value>127.0.0.1:47500</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Since there's only one discovery port available, you can be reasonably sure that a cluster of one node will be formed. You should expect this in Ignite log:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=3.5GB]
```